# Subcategories aren't populating as <option>s - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-select, optgroup

I'm trying to concatenate a string of `<optgroup>`s and `<option>`s based on categories and subcategories.

Currently, I am getting a string that has all the categories first then all of the subcategories. I need it to go `category > subcategories for said category` etc.

The backend has two tables, main categories, and subcategories.

```
Subcategory Table
  id
  title
  main_category_id

Main Category Table
  id
  title
```

In my code below, I am trying to loop through the main categories, adding them to an `<optgroup>`. Before moving to the next main category, I am getting the subcategories for each and adding them as `<option>`s.

```
let select = document.querySelector("#category");
let str = "";

async function getMainCategories() {
    const categoriesURL = "INSERT_URL"
    await fetch(categoriesURL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(async categories => {
      await categories.sort(function(a, b) {
        var nameA = a.title.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
        var nameB = b.title.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
        if (nameA < nameB) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (nameA > nameB) {
          return 1;
        }

        // names must be equal
        return 0;
      }).map(async cat => {
        str += `<optgroup label="${cat.title}">`;
        await getSubcategories(cat.id);
        console.log(str)
        str += '</optgroup>';
      })
    });
    select.innerHTML = "<option disabled selected>Select a category</option>" + str;
}

async function getSubcategories(id) {
    let subcategoriesURL = `INSERT_URL?cat_id=${id}`;

    await fetch(subcategoriesURL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(subcategories => {
      subcategories.sort(function(a, b) {
        var nameA = a.title.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
        var nameB = b.title.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
        if (nameA < nameB) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (nameA > nameB) {
          return 1;
        }

        // names must be equal
        return 0;
      }).map(sub => {
        return str += `<option value="${sub.id}">${sub.title}</option>`;
      })
    });
}
getMainCategories();
```

Comment: I would rather fetch categories, then fetch subcategories, and I would wait for all requests being done before building a nested JS structure that I could browse to create the corresponding HTML (I'm thinking of the Visitor pattern). This way you split data loading, data processing, and printing.

Comment: An easier way to sort alphabetically: `.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title, 'en', { sensitivity: 'base' }))`